# Tengo este problema, se repite la ultima palabra de la clave en el cifrado viginere que estoy creando

Tags: java

Este es mi codigo, esta hecho en java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hello{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        sc.useDelimiter("\n");
        
        String letras = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String clave = "LOUP";
        System.out.println("Escribe una frase/palabra");
        String frase = sc.next();

        
        

        String texto = codificar(letras, frase, clave);
        System.out.println("La frase ingresada fue codificada en clave Viginier, ahora esta es tu frase " +texto);
    }
        public static String codificar(String letras, String texto, String clave){
             String textoCodificado = "";
             texto = texto.toUpperCase();
             String extenderclave = "";
             for (int y = 0, j = 0; y < texto.length(); y++) {
                 if(texto.charAt(y) == (char)32) {
                     extenderclave += (char)32;
                 } else {
                     if (j < clave.length()) {
                         extenderclave += clave.charAt(j);
                         j++;
                     } else {
                         j = 0;
                         extenderclave += clave.charAt(j);
                         j++;
                     }
                 }
             }
             System.out.println(extenderclave +" Esta es tu clave ahora" );
         }
     }
```

Quiero hacer un cifrado viginere, pero el primer problema que se me presenta es que la clave se tiene que extender tanto como la frase/palabra ingresada y lo hace, pero se repite x alguna razon la ultima letra de la clave al final, y eso hace que al cifrar la palabra, se cifre con una letra demas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El metodo [`useDelimiter()`](https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-scanner-usedelimiter-method#:%7E:text=The%20useDelimiter()%20is%20a,Scanner%20useDelimiter(Pattern%20pattern)%20Method)de clase de escáner  se utiliza para establecer el patrón de delimitación del escáner que se está utilizando.Es decir

al usar `sc.useDelimiter("\n");` estas agregando un valor extra al valor capturado por scanner.

Si ingresases la palabra `hola` lo correcto seria que `texto.length()` sea 4 pero con el uso de `sc.useDelimiter("\n");` devolvera 5..
de querer capturar frases con espacio ,debes hacer uso de `nextLine()` en vez de `next()`

```
System.out.println("Escribe una frase/palabra");
String frase = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!